# Using a nested key inside foreach

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I want to implement double lookup function,

I need to set value of `<Node2>`  element inside `<Product>` with value of outer xml.
The relation to this xml, is via `<lookup>` element via value of `<ID>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Products>
    <lookup>
        <Ref>
            <ID>1</ID>
            <outer_id>110</outer_id>
        </Ref>
        <Ref>
            <ID>2</ID>
            <outer_id>220</outer_id>
        </Ref>
    </lookup>   
    <Product>
        <item>
         <ID>1</ID>
         <Node2>A</Node2>
        </item> 
        <item>
         <ID>2</ID>
         <Node2>B</Node2>
        </item>             
    </Product>  
</Products>


<xsl:stylesheet
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:param name="f1" select="'xml2.xml'"/>
    <xsl:variable name="doc1" select="document($f1)"/>

    <xsl:key name="k1" match="Products/Product" use="@prodId"/>

    <xsl:key name="look" match="Products/lookup/Ref/outer_id" use="../ID"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="Products/Product/item/Node2">

        <xsl:variable name="cur" select="current()"/>
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="key('look', normalize-space(normalize-space($cur/../ID)))">                 
                    <xsl:for-each select="$doc1">
                        <xsl:value-of select="key('k1', key('look', normalize-space(normalize-space($cur/../ID))))/@myvalue"/>
                    </xsl:for-each>
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:copy>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It looks like a not very complex task, but it doesn't work for me, I guess due the fact that my 'context' is changed inside `foreach` and it's not possible to use 'look' key anymore.

Please suggest a solution.

Comment: Your XSLT references a second XML documen; 'xml2.xml'. Can you show a sample of this in your question, and the output you expect? Thanks!

Comment: What does `normalize-space(normalize-space(..))` achieve that `normalize-space(...)` wouldn't?

Comment: yes:), after testing keys separately, I copied the content inside the other key /

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem indeed one of context, as within the `<xsl:for-each select="$doc1">` statement, any use of `key('look', ...)` will be within the context of `$doc1` and not the original XML document.

In this case, the solution is simply to evaluate the key and put the results in a variable prior to the `xsl:for-each`, and use the variable inside.

```
<xsl:template match="Products/Product/item/Node2">
    <xsl:variable name="cur" select="current()"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:variable name="look" select="key('look', normalize-space(normalize-space($cur/../ID)))" />
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$look">                 
                <xsl:for-each select="$doc1">
                    <xsl:value-of select="key('k1', $look)/@myvalue"/>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```